# How can I add a map to an image view in javafx using GMapsfx and also get the location of a place without getting a null pointer exception

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, javafx

How can I add a map to an image view in javafx using GMapsfx 2.12.0 and also get the location of a place in longitude and latitude and in name of location without getting a null pointer exception in my code at line

```
 map = new GoogleMap();
```

.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.MapComponentInitializedListener;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.GoogleMap;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.LatLong;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapOptions;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MapTypeIdEnum;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.Marker;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.MarkerOptions;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.MapLibraryLoadBridge;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.JavascriptRuntime;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.JavascriptObject;
//import static com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.ExsltDynamic.map;
//import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeArray.map;
//import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeDebug.map;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class SecurityGUIController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton locationradiobtn;
    @FXML
    private TextField locationtxt;
    @FXML
    private ImageView MapImageView;
    @FXML
    private Button emmergencyButton;
    
    private GoogleMapView mapView;
    
    private GoogleMap map;

@FXML
    private void GetLocation(ActionEvent event) {
        double latposbtn = 0.0, longposbtn = 0.0;
mapView = new GoogleMapView();
        
        map = new GoogleMap();
latposbtn = map.getCenter().getLatitude();
        longposbtn = map.getCenter().getLongitude();
 if (locationradiobtn.isSelected()){
        
        System.out.println(latposbtn);
        //locationtxt.setText("latposbtn, longposbtn");
        
    }    
    }
```

Comment: From my recent testing of GMapsFX and Google Maps in a JavaFX WebView in general (which is how GMapsFX works), for recent versions of JavaFX and Google Maps, the functionality is completely broken.  It used to work a long time ago.  There is no fix or workaround that I am aware of.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that information but they keep on bringing out new jar libraries which i think should work though I have not tried all. Any other library which i can use with Javafx for maps which you know of as a jar file as that is easier for me to program with.

Comment: "*Any other library which i can use with Javafx for maps"* ->  No, there aren't any that I know of.  Perhaps you can find something that might work based on open street map rather than JavaFX, or Bing maps, but I don't know. Anyway, [library recommendations are off topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource).